# Preserving Paragraphs When Pasting into Lyx

Tags: copy-paste, lyx

So very annoyingly: When you copy and paste from say Word into LyX, you lose all your paragraphs, emboldenings, etc. Is there any way to preserve these things?

Answer (score 0):

Text decorations won't copy over, but to preserve line breaks you can use CTRL+SHIFT+V to paste it in, which corresponds to the Edit>Paste Special>Plain Text in the menu